# Examples of non-polynomial analytic homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

For any odd positive integer $k$, the map $f_k(x):=x^k$ is both an analytic function and a homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$, since $f_k^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[k]{x}$ is bijective an analytic.  In fact, this shows that it is a biholomorphism.

Are there examples of biholomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, more generally examples of analytic homeomorphisms (not there is no requirement for the inverse to be more than continuous here), which are *not* polynomials?

Comment: Side note: for $\mathbb{R}$, as José Carlos Santos noted in his answer, the answer is yes. However for $\mathbb{C}$ the only functions satisfying your requirements are translations

Comment: HomEomorphism : $f$ is bijective continuous and $f^{-1}$ is continuous. Biholomorphism : $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are also analytic, equal to their Taylor series near each point (we use this word only for functions between open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$). Homomorphism : a map between groups or rings preserving the corresponding operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take $\sinh$, for instance.

On the other hand, $x\mapsto\sqrt[k]x$ isn't even differentiable at $0$. So, it's not analytic.

Comment: Are there other "well-known" examples (besides some rescaling/shift of $\sinh$)?

Comment: Sure. For instance, $x\mapsto x+e^x$.

Comment: So I guess $x + \sinh(kx)$ works for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$, since the map is analytic, monotone increasing, and subjective onto $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Only if $k\geqslant0$. Otherwise, it's not a bijection.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x + \tanh(kx)$ and yes for $k\geq 0$

Comment: Yes, that will work too.